# Is it legitimate to use bootstrap to estimate regression parameter with hypothetical sample data?

Tags: regression, bootstrap, parameterization

Consider a simple OLS model:

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2  +\epsilon
$$

Suppose $x_2$ is dummy variable which has value either 1 or 0 and the model is successfully fitted with collected data.

As to my specific case, I would like to make some predictions of $y$ based on $x_2$. For example, what is the mean value of $y$ if 15% of $x_2$ is 1 and others are 0?  Since my model is used on some observation data rather than experimental data, it is impossible for me to collect $x_2$ with values like what I would expect right now(however, this situation is possible to be observed in the future). I am thinking of using bootstrapping to estimate $y$ under specific situation I expect.

Specifically, I constructed 500 sample of $x_2$ data with %15 values are randomly assigned as 1 and use the fitted model to predict $y$ (data of $x_1$ remain unchanged). I then can get a distribution of the mean of predicted $y$. I am wondering is my approach legitimate to generate the expected mean value of $y$ under the designated hypothetical situation of $x_2$? Are there any other things I need to take care of? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually much simpler than that. If all you want to do is, say, estimate the mean $y$ you would observe in a new sample in which $x_2$ is 1 for 15% of the observations and 0 otherwise and $x_1$ is always 2, just compute:

$.15(β_0 + 2β_1 + 1β_2) \\\ + (1 - .15)(β_0 + 2β_1 + 0β_2) \\= β_0 + 2β_1 + .15β_2 \; .$

You would only use bootstrapping in this case if you wanted to estimate the uncertainty in your prediction of $y$, as opposed to giving just a point estimate.